# I have a Champion 120V generator, I want to use it to plug into a preinstalled/wired 240volt split phase outlet

Tags: 120-240v

I have a new champion generator, 120volt at 20 to 30amp. The previous home owner had  the same unit but 240 volt. The home has a professionally installed system for power backup but has a 4 pin 240 volt outlet as per photo.

My question is, can I adapt my unit to the 240 volt system which I think is split phase because it also runs a 1.5HP well pump motor?

[image: champion generator]

Comment: Unlikely unless you can the owner’s manual

Comment: No chance.  Call Customer Tech support

Comment: Any reason you can't take this generator back and get a bigger one?

Comment: This generator can run 1 leg of a 240v system. No 240v loads if your well pump is 120v this generator could push most wells and a refrigerator but anything more would be pushing it unless you have a shallow well usually 1/2hp sometimes 3/4hp I would want a 240v 5kw for minimum power for a home with a well. Your generator is only rated for 12.5 amp continuous so with a well starting at the same time as the fridge it may not hold up so a larger generator and 240v would be my suggestion 5kw with peak 6.5kw will run most homes at a minimum level of gas heat or wood burning with fans for heat.

Comment: I hope you want to plug that into an inlet, not an outlet.

Answer (score 2):

### Nope, no chance.

You can't get there from here.

The only way to do it involves some wild back-flips with a 5 KVA 120/240V transformer, but those are $400+.  (you can occasionally get a find on Craigslist, but *even then*, the price will be greater than the price diff between this one and the generator you need.)

So back it goes.... if the well is a priority.

If it's not a priority, then *maybe* we can hook this up, but we'll need to see a much more detailed look at your generator interlock or transfer switch equipment, and how the panel is wired.